# Why all results in CNN Keras the same

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, keras, artificial-intelligence, conv-neural-network

I have a problem in my CNN code in Keras
after building simple neural-network architecture and run the prediction function
all predictions have  the same resutls
My own data divided into two classes (healthy , unhealthy)
I thought before that the problem was the complex of nature of pictures
but when i applied code in another data contain from (White image , black image) 
i found the same results 
What is the cause of the problem in your opinion

---

My architecture CNN code

```py
#batch_size to train
batch_size = 32
# number of output classes
nb_classes = 2
# number of epochs to train
nb_epoch = 2
# number of convolutional filters to use
nb_filters = 32
# size of pooling area for max pooling
nb_pool = 2
# convolution kernel size
nb_conv = 3

HIDDEN_LAYERS = 4

sgd = SGD(lr=0.5, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.6, nesterov=True)

Y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(Y_train, nb_classes)
Y_test = np_utils.to_categorical(Y_test, nb_classes)

X_train /= 255
X_test /= 255

# first set of CONV => RELU => POOL layers
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(20, (5, 5), padding="same",
input_shape=shape_ord))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(nb_pool, nb_pool), strides=(2, 2)))

# second set of CONV => RELU => POOL layers
model.add(Conv2D(50, (5, 5), padding="same"))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(nb_pool, nb_pool), strides=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
# first (and only) set of FC => RELU layers
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
#model.add(Dropout(0.5))


# softmax classifier
model.add(Dense(nb_classes))
model.add(Activation(K.sigmoid))
#categorical_crossentropy
model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy", optimizer=sgd,metrics=["accuracy"])
```

---

The results
[The result of predictions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K7gHv.png)

Comment: What are the shapes of `Y_train` and `Y_test` ?

Comment: The shapes for `Y_train`  and `Y_test` is Nx2 but when i try to keep it Nx1 I got error **ValueError: Error when checking target: expected activation_144 to have shape (2,) but got array with shape (1,)**

Comment: Try changing `nb_classes` to 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have a final sigmoid layer and are using `binary_crossentropy`, try encoding your labels as an Nx1 vector of 0s and 1s.

The lines below are converting them to an Nx2 vector, which you would typically use with a final softmax layer.

```
Y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(Y_train, nb_classes)
Y_test = np_utils.to_categorical(Y_test, nb_classes)
```

If `Y_train` and `Y_test` are already Nx1 of 0s and 1s, try commenting the above lines out.